Jetson Xavier USB HUB design
I created a custom carrier board for jetson xavier. In that i added one USB 2.0 HUB. So can i take one USB 2.0 Pair from HUB and other RX and TX connections directly from Jetson and make a USB 3.0 Port?

USB 2 and USB 3 works as two independent subsystems, even in a "USB 3" hub chip it's essentially a USB 2 block and a USB 3 block, so your idea definitely works in practice (although I'm not sure whether the USB specifications have anything to say about that...)

That should be perfectly valid way to do it. I have seen similar designs in other contexts for how USB3 and USB2 are routes through various hubs to connectors or onboard chips.
